# ngRepeat error with calling a function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've an array and I'm looping over this array and calling a function into this ng-repeat and this function is in link function of a directive 
so my problem is, ng-repeat looping only twice (length of array items) but calling directive link function more than twice
Here my code snippet

```
link:function(scope){ 
      $scope.test = function() {
        console.log('sssss');
     }}
```

and template is

`<div ng-repeat ="item in items> {{test()}}></div>`

please help me to prevent calling test function more than items length.

Answer (score 1):

You should do this,

```
<div ng-repeat ="item in items" ng-init="test()"> </div>
```

Comment: could you explain why you use niInit?

Comment: @Wa'elJazmaty The function gets called whenever the div is initialized

Answer (score 0):

Reason `test()` is getting called more times than length of array items is 
because of this `{{test()}}`.

AngularJS registers a `watcher` for `{{}}`(binding) in view.

This `watcher` keeps track of whether value has been changed or not(it compares the old value to new value). `watcher`'s expression(in your case, `test()`) gets evaluated *atleast* once in this process.

You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682092/how-does-data-binding-work-in-angularjs).

Thats the reason your `test()` is getting more number of times than length of array.

```
<div ng-repeat ="item in items" ng-init="test()"> </div>
```

If you use `ng-init`, `test()` will only be initialized(called) once per each repeat.